# Can you explain why this code has this output?

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-programming

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a[7];
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        a[i]=i;
        a[6-i]=i;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

can you explain me why does this code output this:

```
6 5 4 3 4 5 6
```

thanks.

Comment: What output do you expect and why?

Comment: Because that's what the C standard says it should. What output do you expect? Why are you surprised?

Answer (score 4):

This

```c
a[6-i]=i;
```

Would assign the array like

```c
a[6]=0
a[5]=1
a[4]=2
a[3]=3
```

And so on. However

```c
a[i]=i;
```

would assign it like

```c
a[0]=0
a[1]=1
And this goes on.
```

Since `a[6]` has been assigned to 0, it is replaced on the 7th loop `a[6]=6` and so forth. I don't know what you expected.

Comment: No. It doesn't memorize values, just overwrites them. while `a[6] = 0` is true at the beginning, `a[6] = 6` overwrites that later (I must sound like a crazy person, but a comment was here a second ago)

Comment: but how? doesn't the memorized value in [a[6]=0]? how can the the [a[0]=6]but still [a[6]=6] i just don't get, if the last memorized values in the array starts from [a[6-i]=i] and how can there be a 7th loop if the condition wants it to be strictly [i<7]

Comment: There is a seventh loop because `i` starts at 0. That means that it goes
```c
0 < 7,
1 < 7,
2 < 7,
...,
5 < 7,
6 < 7,
```
See my other post for everything else

Comment: thank you so much for bearing with me. but i just really cannot understand how it overwrites here  a[6-i]=i and still the other half of the output still prints, 3 4 5 6

Comment: @jeram once i > 3, a[i] writes on the second half and a[6-i] writes on the first. So everything is overwritten, otherwise you would have 1234321

Answer (score 2):

When you don't understand why your program is acting a certain way, the best way is to debug it. To do that you should use a debugger like gdb, which is a great tool that you really should learn to use it, especially since you're a beginner.
Here is a [tutorial for beginners](https://cotonne.github.io/gdb/2019/07/14/gdb-beginner-guide.html). You should also read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Now to your question, since your code is small, we can debug it manually by unrolling it, with U meaning Undefined value :

- when `i == 0`, you have `a = {0, U, U, U, U, U, 0}`
- when `i == 1`, you have `a = {0, 1, U, U, U, 1, 0}`
- when `i == 2`, you have `a = {0, 1, 2, U, 2, 1, 0}`
- when `i == 3`, you have `a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0}`

And now that's where your program should have stopped, as it started to overwrite the old values.